# How to redirect to the page after i have use this $.post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm new in using this language but I'm currently doing some testing
When I click edit in below image
[editImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lxQy.png) It won't redirect me to another page,
but I can see the parameter in developer's tools as below
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJfgy.png).

May I know how to do it in the **updatePerson** function?

---

here is the code:

```
<%@page import="Entities.Person.Person"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entities.Person.PersonSessionBeanLocal"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePerson(id) {
        $.post("updatePerson.jsp",
                {id: id}
        , function (result) {
        });
    }
</script>
<%
    try {

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        PersonSessionBeanLocal personBean = (PersonSessionBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/person");

        String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

        List<Person> resList = personBean.searchPerson(keyword);

        out.print("<table border='1' width='100%'>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<th>ID</th>"
                + "<th>Name</th>"
                + "<th>Description</th>"
                + "<th colspan='2'>Actions</th>"
                + "</tr>"
        );

        for (Person p : resList) {
            //out.print(p.toString() + "<br/>");
            out.print("<tr>"
                    + p.toString()
                    //+"<td><input type='button' name='edit' id='edit' value='Edit' onclick='editPerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "<td><input type='button' name='edit' id='edit' value='Edit' onclick='updatePerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenID' name='hiddenID' type='hidden' value='" + p.getId() + "'>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenName' name='hiddenName' type='hidden' value='" + p.getName() + "'>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenDesc' name='hiddenDesc' type='hidden' value='" + p.getDescription() + "'>"
                    + "<td><input type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='Delete' onclick='deletePerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "</tr>"
            //+ "</table>"
            );
        }
        out.print("</table>");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

%>
```

Comment: if you want redirect then **don't** do ajax

Comment: What page do you want to be redirected to? Will there be data sent to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting to another page i show it in the same page using code as below

```
function updatePerson(id) {
    $.post("update.jsp",
            {id: id}
    , function (result) {
        **$("#resultDiv").html(result);**
    });
}
```

then only i pass the updated data into database